# Autolayout Rendering inconsistently across devices

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a series of views each containing a scrollview wrapping various subviews i.e. Collection views, Labels, imagview. I am using auto layout for the first time and some views render fine on some devices but not on others, I have attached previews of views on iPhone 4s, 5, and 6.

[image: Iphone 5 Scrollview wrapping image view and label view is to far right]  [image: iphone 5 scrollview wrapping collection view fine]
[image: iphone 5 scrollview wrapping zoomable image fine] [image: Ssame image here for iPhone 4 top blue IV cut short]
[image: iphone 6 Scrollview wrapping image view and label view is fine]
[image: iphone6 Scrollview wrapping content view cut short to the right]
[image: iphone 6 scrollview wrapping zoomable image fine]

In particular I am not sure how the alignment of the History views appears off centre in iPhone 5 and 4 but fine in 6, and the collection view in iPhone 6 appears cut sort on the right side but not for iPhone 5,4, and lastly how the blue image with label 'Image Title' on top of the zoomable image on iPhone 4s appears to be cut short. I would of thought a error in autolayout would of been consistent across devices ?

Any input appreciated.

Comment: it is not inconsistent rendering, that is just about auto-layout has been set incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're setting absolute widths on some elements. Instead you should be setting distance to the parent `UIView`'s edges. I.e. trailing/leading space to container.

Comment: Ok so should I be setting all sub views to trailing/leading parent container ? Is that same for  setting vertical and horizontal spacing?

Comment: @dancingbush Ideally you at least avoid constant widths and heights. They'll always result in different sizes on different devices. So in most case use relative layouting and don't forget you can set <= or >= constraints instead if just == ones. Check out the constraint priorities as well to help resolve anything that conflicts.

Comment: Played around for a while and  slowly getting the hang of it. Cheers for the advice

Comment: @dancingbush, good luck. Once it "clicks" you'll come to really enjoy using autolayout.

Answer (score 1):

Try to give consistent constraints. Looks like you are just doing leading and top space to superview and maybe you are adding width and height constraints to avoid misplaced views. Try to think like you are doing autoresizing masks before autolayouts. Either try to keep ratio or expand with the container with trailing and bottom space constraints.